# Prevent array to writing to nonexistent index

Tags: c, arrays

I have array of numbers like:

```
int a[10]={1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1};
```

I find position of 2 and then change the value of indexof(2)+4 and -4 to 2 too.

Problem is that indexof(2)+4 does not exist which mean c will overwrite some memory that does not belong to array. How can I stop c to writing into indexes that exceed length of the array?

Comment: Check whether the result is >=10.

Comment: As this is C, array elements should be delimited by `{}`. Or are `[]` also valid?

Comment: You don't - as a programmer, you need to check for yourself that any index you access is valid. You could consider using a library. For example, in C++,  you could use an `std::vector` and call the `at` method.

Comment: @Arc676: good catch. Pretty sure `[]` is not valid. Fails on my compiler, at least. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, there is no built-in checking (i.e. that happens without programmer involvement) to ensure array indexing keeps within bounds.

If you want to access (read or write) `a[i]` then you need to write code check that `i` is a valid index before doing so, and don't access `a[i]` if `i` is invalid.  That means ensuring the value is between `0` and `n-1`, where `n` is known to be the number of elements in the array.

There are various options to obtain or set the value of `n`.   Each have limits on applicability.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sizeof() operator to get the size of the array. Using it you can check whether the value  indexof(2)+4 is greater than the array size before changing the value.

Comment: Don't rely on `sizeof` - an array decays to a pointer in many situations, in particular, via function calls.  And then `sizeof` is useless.

Comment: That's true, Oliver, but if the array has not "decayed" to a pointer, `sizeof` is a definitive way to evaluate its size.